# How to delete all events in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I want to delete some event I need to query something like 
`"DROP EVENT IF EXISTS  eventname"`
But I can't find the command of deleting all the events at one time,must delete event one by one.
Is there some SQL of deleting all events at one time?

```
"DROP EVENT IF EXISTS (SELECT EVENT_NAME FROM  information_schema.EVENTS)"
```

is not working either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

sample one:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.event
    WHERE db = 'myschema'
      AND definer = 'jon@ghidora'
      AND name = 'e_insert';
```

**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-privileges.html**

if you can delete the event with `DROP EVENT IF EXISTS` and re-add it with the new scheduled time.

To permanently delete an event yourself, you can use `DROP EVENT`:

```
DROP EVENT [IF EXISTS] event_name
```

**https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-event.html**

Answer (score 5):

To construct a drop events query, you can do something like this:

```
select concat('drop event if exists ', event_name, ';') from information_schema.events;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS` table to gather all the active events and then construct and run the DROP EVENT statements.

Comment: Please tell me how to construct the statements combine "DROP EVENT.."with "SELECT  `EVENT_NAME` FROM  `information_schema`.`EVENTS` "