# MySQL deleted tables stuck in db

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I getting mysql errors from various apps for example from akeeba backup on my host because some deleted tables are stuck. They aren't visible if I view the DB with phpMyAdmin but if I a do a `SHOW TABLES` or a `SHOW FULL TABLES` or I simply click on the search tab in phpMyAdmin than they are there. And they are causing xyz table doesn't exsists errors.

How can I clompletely remove those. Is it possible to remove them from phpMyAdmin or only with command line?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150272/how-to-delete-all-events-in-mysql/23150699#23150699

Comment: Sorry I'm not a MySQL expert so I don't understand how is deleting events relevant to my question. Could you please explain?

Comment: do you wants to remove the all thing from database

Comment: I only want to get rid of the tables which are already deleted with `DROP TABLE` but somehow the mysql dump still shows them. And I want to keep all other tables.

Comment: It might be the index files. Execute "show table status TABLE_NAME" to see if there's any corrupt files?